# How to show that $(\Lambda^2(g))^g = H^2(g)$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, homological-algebra, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $g$ be a semisimple Lie algebra and $\Lambda^2(g) = g \wedge g \subset g \otimes g$ the exterior square of $g$. Consider the adjoint action of g on $g \wedge g$ and let 
$$(\Lambda^2(g))^g = \{x \in g: x.(a \wedge b) = [x,a] \wedge b + a \wedge [x,b] = 0, \forall x \in g\}$$
be the $g$-invariants of $(\Lambda^2(g))^g$ under the adjoint action. How to show that $(\Lambda^2(g))^g = H^2(g)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The second cohomology group (with values in any finite dimensional module) of a semi simple algebra is zero by the second Whitehead lemma. So if you know how to prove the lemma you need only show that there are no nonzero invariants ;-)

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, thank you very much. How to show that $(\Lambda^2 g)^g$ directly (not use Whitehead lemma)? I asked a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663841/do-we-have-g-wedge-gg-0) (the Whitehead lemma is used).